# How to open multiple RC522 reader device on android things?

Tags: gpio, android, android-things

I use Raspberry pi 3 model B on Android Things.

for RC522 communication, I use https://github.com/Galarzaa90/android-things-rc522

this source success work, only 1 RC522 reader device

but I want 2 RC522 devices.
[image]

if RC522 reader device only 1 connect.

GPIO set

`SDA - GPIO 8 (SPI0 CS0)`
`SCK - GPIO 11 (SPI0 SCLK)`
`MOSI - GPIO 10 (SPI0 MOSI)`
`MISO - GPIO 9 (SPI0 MISO)`
`GND - GND`
`RST - GPIO25`
`3.3V - 3.3V PWR`

is work RC522 device.

and I would like to use 2 RC522 reader devices like the pictures.

this pictures set

`SDA (blue) - SPI0 CS1(GPIO 7) , SPO0 CS0 (GPIO 8)
'SCK (green) - SPI0 SCLK`
`MOSI (yellow) - SPI0 MOSI`
`MISO (orange) - SPI0 MISO`
`GND (red) - GND`
`RST (Brown) - GPIO 25`
`3.3V (black) - 3.3V PWR`

but Only the RC522 device to the left of the picture works.

first when I build with https://github.com/Galarzaa90/android-things-rc522 this source.

all RC522 devices not work.

with a little modification, I was able to operate only one RC522 device on the left.

MainActivity.class

```
private SpiDevice spiDevice;
private SpiDevice spiDevice2;

private static final String SPI_PORT = "SPI0.0";
private static final String SPI_PORT2 = "SPI0.1";

private Rc522 mRc522;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  PeripheralManager pioService = PeripheralManager.getInstance();
  try {
      spiDevice = pioService.openSpiDevice(SPI_PORT);
      spiDevice2 = pioService.openSpiDevice(SPI_PORT2);

      mRc522 = new Rc522(spiDevice, spiDevice2, gpioReset);
 ...
```

Rc522.class

```
private SpiDevice device;
private SpiDevice device2;

private Gpio resetPin;
private int busSpeed = 1000000;
private int busSpeed2 = 13650000;  //13.65khz

public Rc522(SpiDevice spiDevice, SpiDevice spiDevice2, Gpio resetPin) throws IOException {
    this.device = spiDevice;
    this.device2 = spiDevice2;

    initializePeripherals();
}

 /**
 *  Performs the initial configuration on hardware ports
 * @throws IOException if the hardware board had a problem with its hardware ports
 */
 private void initializePeripherals() throws IOException {
    device.setFrequency(busSpeed);
    device2.setFrequency(busSpeed2);
    resetPin.setDirection(Gpio.DIRECTION_OUT_INITIALLY_HIGH);
    initializeDevice();
}

/**
 * Performs the initial device setup and configure the pins used
 */
private void initializeDevice(){
    reset();
    writeRegister(REGISTER_TIMER_MODE, (byte) 0x8D);
    writeRegister(REGISTER_TIMER_PRESCALER_MODE, (byte) 0x3E);
    writeRegister(REGISTER_TIMER_RELOAD_LOW, (byte) 30);
    writeRegister(REGISTER_TIMER_RELOAD_HIGH, (byte) 0);
    writeRegister(REGISTER_TX_MODE, (byte) 0x40);
    writeRegister(REGISTER_MODE, (byte) 0x3D);
    setAntenna(true);
}

 /**
 * Writes to a RC522 register
 * @param address The address to write to
 * @param value The value that will be written
 */
private void writeRegister(byte address, byte value){
    //Log.d(TAG, "writeRegister -->" + address);
    //Log.d(TAG, "writeValue -->" + value);

    byte buffer[] = {(byte) (((address << 1) & 0x7E)), value};
    //Log.d(TAG, "writeBuffer -->" + buffer.toString());
    byte response[] = new byte[buffer.length];
    try {
        device.transfer(buffer, response, buffer.length);
        //device2.transfer(buffer, response, buffer.length);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Reads the current value on the RC522's register
 * @param address The address to read from
 * @return the byte value currently stored in the register
 */
public byte readRegister(byte address){
    byte buffer[] = {(byte) (((address << 1) & 0x7E) | 0x80), 0};
    byte response[] = new byte[buffer.length];
    try {
        device.transfer(buffer, response, buffer.length);
        //device2.transfer(buffer, response, buffer.length);
        return response[1];
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I feel like I might be able to modify `writeRegister()` and `readRegister()` just a little bit.

perhaps,you have opened multiple devices in android things, if you have ever used an RC522 reader device.

please advice for me

thanks..

Comment: It seems like it is using SPI Pheripheral to communicate. Why are you connecting the i2c Pheripheral?

Comment: It looks like you're wiring both peripherals together, is that right? I don't see why you are connecting them together since they connect to separate SPI ports.

Comment: @MaNyYaCk  I use RC522 devices use SPI Pheripheral to communicate.  where is the i2c connecting?

Comment: @NickFelker RC522 https://github.com/Galarzaa90/android-things-rc522 here site is  used the SPI port

Comment: @hyunwookcho Coming from microcontroller background so SDA and SCL are I2C to me. Sorry. Missed the information written in the back ground. You need to pull the chip select line low of the module that you want to send data to. And pull the line high of the module that you dont want to use.

Comment: @MaNyYaCk thanks, but What is mean pull the chip select line low of the module that I want to send data to?

Comment: use the Chip selects as GPIO , Direction : out , 1 for High , 0 for Low.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/things/pio/Gpio#active_high       are you saying this?

Comment: Yes, My guess would be setting direction are DIRECTION_OUT_INITIALLY_HIGH and use setValue function. Do give it a try and ping be back using @ or else I don't getting notified about your comments.

Comment: then 1 rc522 device will open with the `spi0` and another device use GPIO number?

Comment: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/serial-peripheral-interface-spi/slave-select-ss. Check out the multiple slave section.

Comment: Both will use spi0 but the one with Chip Select line as 0/Low will be the active slave

Comment: @MaNyYaCk I am sorry that I do not understand becaus I am short.       first Both will use `spi0`  is right?   so I write `private static fianl String SPI_PORT = "SPI0.0";` `private static final String SPI_PORT2 ="SPI0.1";`

Comment: and I check multiple slave section.     MASTER is    raspberry pi, and SLAVE1 is left rc522 device, and SLAVE2 is right rc522 device.

Comment: and Do you mean to activate each device according to the situation?   use `ACTIVE_LOW` ? is activation at the same time difficult?

Comment: @hyunwookcho only single SPI_PORT. yes, activate device as per situation. Active the device with which you want RPi to communicate.  but not by using ACTIVE_LOW. Idk what that does, but how put LOW or 0 on GPIO pin used for the device chip select

Comment: then I find out how to enable gpio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions should be something like this.

```
private void writeRegister(byte address, byte value,byte sensor_Number){
    //Log.d(TAG, "writeRegister -->" + address);
    //Log.d(TAG, "writeValue -->" + value);

    //Logic to pull the line high for the sensor other than the sensor_Number
    //Logic to pull the line low for the sensor_Number.

    byte buffer[] = {(byte) (((address << 1) & 0x7E)), value};
    //Log.d(TAG, "writeBuffer -->" + buffer.toString());
    byte response[] = new byte[buffer.length];
    try {
        device.transfer(buffer, response, buffer.length);
        //device2.transfer(buffer, response, buffer.length);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public byte readRegister(byte address,byte sensor_Number){
    //Logic to pull the line high for the sensor other than the sensor_Number
    //Logic to pull the line low for the sensor_Number.

    byte buffer[] = {(byte) (((address << 1) & 0x7E) | 0x80), 0};
    byte response[] = new byte[buffer.length];
    try {
        device.transfer(buffer, response, buffer.length);
        //device2.transfer(buffer, response, buffer.length);
        return response[1];
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Do write those commented logic yourself because I am useless when it comes to cpp.

edit : I don't know what the intialize device does but if it is configuring the RC522 Module, you need to do that for both the modules.