# How to control SPI1 gpio port on Android-Things?

Tags: gpio, spi, android-things

[image]

Hello

Recently, I use Android-Things on Raspberry pi.
and I want reader tag on RC522

so, I decided to refer to source in on Git-hub https://github.com/Galarzaa90/android-things-rc522

first I try only 1 RC522 device. is success work.
but in the end, what I want  two RC522 devices are working.
because My project is commute system. 
I want when employee go to work, reader tag on RC522 devices.
and when employee go to home, reader tag on Another RC522 devices.

so I need two RC522 devices.
but this source two RC522 reader fail.
so I search raspberry pi gpio port.

current this source,

```
use 

1. GPIO 8 (SPI0 CS0) -SDA

2. GPIO 11 (SPI0 SCLK) - SCK

3. GPIO 10 (SPI0 MOSI) - MOSI

4. GPIO 9  (SPI0 MISO) - MISO

5. GND   - GND

6. GPIO 25 - RST

7. 3.3V PWR - 3.3V
```

is only 1 RC522 device.

I want add 1 RC522 device

use

```
1. GPIO 7  (SPI0 CS1) - SDA 

2. GPIO 21 (SPI1 SCLK) - SCK

3. GPIO 20 (SPI1 MOSI) - MOSI

4. GPIO 19 (SPI1 MISO) - MISO

5. GND - GND

6. GPIO 12 -RST

7. 3.3V PWR - 3.3V
```

but this source seems to be able to modify this part.

```
private static final String SPI_PORT = "SPI0.1";
private static final String PIN_RESET = "BCM12";
```

to sum up,

1. it is possible, connect 2 RC522 devices?
2. it is possible how to control SPI1 gpio port ?

thanks.:)

Comment: I think you need to see my answer on you previous question. You don't need different SPI ports for each module. One can connect as many as module they need on the single SPI

Comment: @MaNyYaCk What previous answer?

Comment: @Ingo sorry, should have added the link https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/87093/how-to-open-multiple-rc522-reader-device-on-android-things